# Laravel routes/web.php and routes/api.php

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, rest, api

The `routes/web.php` have common application routes, Like showing the views, Getting the data from the form to a controller method.

The `routes/api.php` will have routes for getting records of the tables/entities in `JSON`. Updating, Deleting etc via api routes ?

**Question 1** : How will i use my `routes/api.php` routes to get, delete, Update data/Records ?

**Question 2** : Android app will be able to use my api ? If yes, How ?

**Question 3** : The API should have a controller `ApiController` ?

*Let the kid know the stuff* !

Thanks

Comment: which laravel version are you using?

Comment: @boroboris Laravel 5.4.......

Comment: Q1: You will need to write your own logic on how that happens. Q2: Sure, you'll need to use routes/api.php for that Q3: The naming of controllers doesn't matter at all. Could as well have 3 and name them Luke, Barbie and MyBeautifulController.

Answer (score 0):

## 1:

Put this into your `RouteServiceProvider` file:

```
    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->webNamespace], function ($router) {
        require app_path('routes/web.php');
    });


    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->apiNamespace], function ($router) {
        require app_path('routes/api.php');
    });
```

## 1.1 in routes/web.php file (alternative):

```
require_once "../../routes/api.php";
```

## 2:

yes. use your routes as you would use them in any other frontend application. For example: `localhost/api/myAndroidRoute`

## 3:

doesn't really matter. you can use one controller for all the routes, or one controller for each route. Whichever option you like. If you have a lot of code, separate it into different controllers for better readibility.
For example:

```
Route::get('api/sampledata', 'ApiController@getSampleData'); // controller@function
Route::get('api/otherdata', 'SomeOtherController@getOtherData');
```

or

```
Route::get('api/sampledata', 'AllmightyController@getSampleData');
Route::get('web/otherdata', 'AllmightyController@getOtherData');
```